# AFNetworking send parameters as form data

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, afnetworking-2

I have been trying to send parameters as form data by setting content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded into HTTPHeaderField but the request is not going through for only above content type, my code works for type application/json.
So, I am not able to rectify the actual problem hence the request is not going through.

Below is my code ::

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:60];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:requestAuthorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_id"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_os"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_name"];

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given on the AFNetworking page on Github. [AFNetworking Library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

You can do this by simply using following example:-

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"key": @"xxx"};

[manager POST:@"http://test.com" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Do you want to upload any large file to server?

Comment: No, i just want to send parameters as form data, thats why I am setting [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: Please do not set this in your code and try:-  [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: Still not able to go through, the API is accessible by Advance Rest client but not by AFNetworking i.e. not able to POST parameters as form data.

Comment: Strange behaviour AFNetworking has, I tried your your code once again without changing my previous values and it worked now.
Thanks

Comment: Perfect answer for me